# Saving Drupal MaxBlog configuration causes PDOException

Tags: drupal

I am trying to configure a Drupal MaxBlog but when I try to save the content it displays this error message:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mintgrap_mint_blog.pathauto_state' 
>       doesn't exist: SELECT 1 AS expression FROM {pathauto_state} pathauto_state WHERE ( (entity_type = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (entity_id = :db_condition_placeholder_1) );
>       Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => node [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 9 ) in pathauto_entity_state_save() (line 492 of 
>       /home/mintgraphics/public_html/blog/mint/sites/all/modules/pathauto/pathauto.module
>       The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

What is causing it and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

update your pathauto module to the latest: https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto

after you update it, make sure you update your database with any changes by going to www.yourdomain.com/update.php

your error states its missing the pathauto table. a reinstall of pathauto should do it.